# Using Custom Widgets in Qt Designer for PySide6 MDI application

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyside6

I refer to the PySide MDI example in PySide project repository at  https://github.com/pyside/Examples/blob/master/examples/mainwindows/mdi/mdi.py. I tried to adopt the same to PySide6 after changing the import reference to from PySide to PySide6. It is working fine in current form.

After making sure that the example works with PySide6, I made following additions:
Implemented a new Widget in Qt Designer (using exe installed in project VE using `pip install pyside6`) with just one **QTextEdit** widget on this form. The python code generated by designer is as below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'FormWidget01uyjQCJ.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 6.4.0
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QSizePolicy, QTextEdit, QWidget)

class Ui_FormWidget01(object):
    def setupUi(self, FormWidget01):
        if not FormWidget01.objectName():
            FormWidget01.setObjectName(u"FormWidget01")
        FormWidget01.resize(700, 500)
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(FormWidget01)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(u"textEdit")
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 681, 481))

        self.retranslateUi(FormWidget01)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(FormWidget01)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, FormWidget01):
        FormWidget01.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("FormWidget01", u"Form Widget", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

In the mdi.py application, I added the following class for newly generated child on pattern of `class MdiChild(QTestEdit)` in the above example:

```
class FormWidget01(Ui_FormWidget01):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FormWidget01, self).__init__()

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.isUntitled = True
```

Finally, I updated `class MainWindow(QMainWindow)` as below:

1. Added new function on pattern of `newfile(self)`:

```
    def newFw01(self):
        _fw01 = self.createFormWidget01()
        _fw01.show()
```

2. Added new function on pattern of `createMdiChild(self)`:

```
    def createFormWidget01(self):
        fw01 = FormWidget01()
        fw01.resize(400, 300)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(fw01)

        return fw01
```

3. And updated `createActions(self)`:

```
        self.newFw01Act = QAction(QIcon(':/images/new.png'), "&New FW01", self,
                shortcut=QKeySequence.New, statusTip="Create a new FW",
                triggered=self.newFw01)
```

When I run the updated program and click action for new widget, I get the following error:

```
  File "S:\***\newmdi\mdiapp.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
AttributeError: 'FormWidget01' object has no attribute 'setAttribute'
```

At this point, I realized that C++ code generated by the Designer initiate form is like this:

```
class Ui_FormWidget01
{
public:
    QTextEdit *textEdit;

    void setupUi(QWidget *FormWidget01)
    {
        if (FormWidget01->objectName().isEmpty())
            FormWidget01->setObjectName("FormWidget01");
        FormWidget01->resize(700, 500);
        textEdit = new QTextEdit(FormWidget01);
        textEdit->setObjectName("textEdit");
...
```

If I change the python UI class from `class Ui_FormWidget01(object):` to `class Ui_FormWidget01(QWidget):`, replacing **object** with **QWidget**, the action works but produces a minimized and blank instance of Ui_FormWidget01. There is no QTextEdit visible on it.

I'm not pro at coding and not sure what is going wrong.

In partcular, I need to understand if:

1. It is possible to create a custom Widget in Qt Designer and use it as MdiChild in Qt MDI application Framework?
2. If a child widget initialized with **QTextEdit** works as MDI child but not a child with initialized with **object**, what could be restrictions on type of an MDI child?

Any clue or explanation is welcome.

Comment: `class FormWidget01(QWidget, Ui_FormWidget01):` and `self.setupUi(self)` in the `__init__` after super.

Comment: The examples for PySide6 are [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/examples?h=6.4.0) ([mdi example](https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/examples/widgets/mainwindows/mdi?h=6.4.0)).

Comment: @musicamate - It worked. Did not need to change Designer generated code. If you can please post this as Answer, I can accept. Thank you!

Comment: @ekhumoro - I started with same example and extended it. The problem was correct initiation of custom widget, which is not clear with standard QTextEdit widget directly used in this example . Thanks.

Comment: @Ajay it *is* clear as long as you consider what you're inheriting from. The mdi example code shows that `MdiChild` inherits from QTextEdit, which is a QWidget subclass, while uic classes (like your `Ui_FormWidget01`) are just a plain python objects (as shown by its declaration: `class Ui_FormWidget01(object):`), which obviously don't provide QWidget functions such as `setAttribute()`. If you want to use uic "form classes" for inheritance, you need to *also* inherit from the Qt widget class, and explicitly call `self.setupUi(self)`.

Comment: @Ajay The examples you linked to are for PySide (Qt4), which is long since obsolete. The ones I linked to are for PySide6 (Qt6).